# CSS FATHER SELECTOR

Tags: css, css-selectors

```css
.background{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: ;
}
input:checked ~ div{
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
  <input type="checkbox" id="hamburguesa">
 <label for="hamburguesa">click here</label>

<div class="background">aasd</div>
```

how can i dothe first result on the second snippet?
there is some way to select a father element?

i want change events using only css without js

```css
    .background{
      width: 200px;
      height: 100px;
      background: ;
    }
    input:checked ~ div{
      background: blue;
    }
```

```html
<div class="hambur">
  <input type="checkbox" id="hamburguesa">
 <label for="hamburguesa">click here</label>
</div>
<div class="background">aasd</div>
```

Comment: This is not possible with CSS only.

Answer (score 1):

CSS Selector Level 4 has a selector called ":has", but it isn't compatible with any browser yet, so you'll have to use javascript/jquery for now.

[:has()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)

This is probably the best solution you can find right now: 
[Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)